# 'There is no editor available' error in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I tried to select designer view in VS 2010 I get this error:

> There is no editor available for
>   'c:\user\teadrinkinggeek\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\websites\website2\About.aspx'.
>
> Make sure the application for the file
>   type (.aspx) is installed.

I opened a different website and the error is still there.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you give us any more context? Has that worked before on the same computer? Have you recently (re-)installed Visual Studio? What version of Visual Studio—do you have one of the Express editions, or the full version?

Comment: First time I've used Visual Studio 2010. It compiles and run programs that I enter. But when I select Designer, it come up with that error. I also have Visual Web 2010 installed. The designer is working fine for that. At the moment I'm trying a repair (have to download entire package from the web again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a ‘painful’ decision to uninstall all things related to VS 2010, and re-install from scratch.  After 6 hours of troubleshooting, re-installing VS 2010 again, it worked.

**Note:** I initially run Visual Web Developer side-by-side with VS 2010. I uninstalled that package too.  Maybe the two packages caused the problem?  However I spoke to one developer on Twitter, he said he had no problem with both packages working side-by-side. Maybe it was the way I initially installed them.

If you have the same problem, please backup your work, projects etc, before you uninstall, otherwise you might run into more problems.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue and it was easly resolved by the following:

`Right-Click on the .edmx file --> Open With --> ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer` and then `Set as Default`.

Comment: This did it for me in vs 2012

Answer (score 2):

This problem is somewhat difficult to diagnose. The easiest thing is probably to re-install your copy of Visual Studio. Most likely, something got corrupted during the installation, or you failed to install a crucial component required for opening ASPX files.

Aside from that, there is one trick that I've seen work before. I suppose it's worth a try before you go through the trouble of re-installing. Here are the steps:

1. Open a new command prompt window.
2. Navigate to the directory path in which you installed Visual Studio.
   <sub>(I have no experience with the Express editions, so I'm not sure if the paths and names of the executables are the same as the</sub>

   <sup>full versions. I suspect they're probably not. Thus, the best way to get this information is right-clicking on your shortcut icon.</sup>
3. Execute the following command, where "`devenv`" is the name of the executable you use to start
   the Visual Studio IDE:

   ```
   devenv /resetskippkgs
   ```

Comment: I can't find that executable. Maybe is isn't available on express edition?

Comment: The executable is in: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`  (you may want to replace the version in the path based on your version of visual studio - Visual Studio 2010=10.0; Visual Studio 2012=11.0; Visual Studio 2013=12.0; Visual Studio 2015=14.0; Visual Studio "15"=15.0)

Comment: Didn't help. Also, on my system, despite being 64-bit system & Windows, the *devenv.exe* file was found in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` .

Comment: @Br.Bill That's not weird. Visual Studio is a 32-bit app, so it would always go in the Program Files (x86) folder. I don't know what you mean by "didn't help". Did you mean that `/resetskippkgs` didn't work? More information would be required to solve the problem. Consider asking a new question and providing all relevant context.

Comment: I do mean that `/resetskippkgs` did not change anything. I am still experiencing the problem described with VS2010. There's no more context to offer except that this is happening for all file types, not just .aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happens because one of the references of the project are making problems.

**Solution:**

Build your solution to Identify the reference that is making problems, remove the reference and add it again, after rebuilding your project everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this issue with Visual Basic Express 2008 for ages and have tried just about every solution that I came across. As per the solution from Cody Gray I opened a command prompt at `c:\program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE` and then executed

```
vbexpress /resetskippkg
```

When VB Express 2008 opened all was well and I could at last access the form designer window!  Worked a treat!!!

Answer (score 1):

I switched my target framework for this project from older 2.0 to 4.0 and designer opened.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `devenv /resetskippkgs` command with no results. However, after it failed, I played around with the form properties. When I clicked on *frmFormName.vb* in the Solution Explorer, the properties window showed something different for "build action" than did my other form. I changed this property to "compile" to match my other form. Now, everything is working fine. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to VS 2010 and I had this same problem. I spent hours on the net to no avail. Out of desperation I created a new solution and the copied all my existing files into it's directory. I then entered my new app and said "show all files". All my 'old' files were displayed, with "white icons" . I then right-clicked each file and said add to project for each one. I then rebuilt all and everything is back to normal and it did not take long. Hope it can help someone. I know it does not sound to professional, but hey, it works.
Arthur Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Well I faced the same issue. I right clicked on edmx file and opened it with Entity Data model  designer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also receive this message if the Build Action property is set to None on the (.cs/.vb) file.

Click on the (.cs/.vb) file in your project, look at the Properties Window (press F4 if not visible), make sure that the Build Action property is set to Compile.

Its a really misleading error message in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered the same problem in Visual Studio 2008.
But don't worry folks it's damn simple to solve.

> Just follow the simple steps stated as follows:

1. Close all the opened programs on your machine.
2. Go to Command Prompt window
3. Give the following command :
   ***c:\program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE***
4. Now run:
   ***devenv /resetskippkgs***

♦Enjoy coding my pals♦

Comment: It should be:

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE` .

The path you gave definitely won't be the location.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that issue just check your reference and fix those that has "!".

This happened to me also: related/additional notes related to this fix.

Solution Explorer

--> Expand References

--> Right click on the item with "Yellow Triange w/ "!" point"

```
--> select "Remove"
```

Open the "Build" Menu at the top

--> select: Rebuild "filename"

Double clicking on the from name in Solution Explorer would then open the from normally for me.

Comment: I have this problem and none of my references have "!". So this can't really help.