# The Visual Studio HTM Editor Package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I reinstalled Visual Studio pro 2010 due to [an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932182/there-is-no-editor-available-error-in-vs-2010).

I loaded VS and I now get this error:

> The Visual Studio HTM Editor Package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of anothe extension.
>
> You can get more information by running the application together with the /log parameter on the command line, and then examining
> the file c:\users\lee\appdata\roaming\microsoft\visualstudio\10.0\activitylog.xml

Any ideas where to go from here.

Comment: I also had some problems with Visual Studio failing to load a specific package and the recommended action of running VS with the `log` parameter proved to be enough to find the source of the problem. You should try that, if you haven't already.

Comment: This just happened to me.  For whatever reason it was enough for me to just restart VS.  Prior to the restart when I went to an aspx page it didn't syntax highlight it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full uninstall of Anything Visual Studio 2010/Express related, followed by a reinstall, it worked.

Comment: did you mean to say all visual studio related IDEs..ie., VWD, VC#, VB, VC++ whatever installed in the system ??  because I tried with complete uninstall of VWD, but without uninstalling VC# & VB.. and it didn't solve the issue.. :(

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by doing following steps,I am using VS Express 2012 and got the same error as mentioned above.

1)Delete(Always do remember to Backup your data) the AppData file from following location(Delete 10.0/11.0 whatever your version of VS)

a)if VS 10
   C:\Users\"UserName"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

b)if VS Express
   C:\Users\"UserName"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSWinExpress\11.0

2)Update VS version from this site
    [MSDN Site](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=51)

or directly from MSDN site[This](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?ProductId=49)

3)Restart VS and enjoy