# Visual Studio 2010 package did not load correctly for uninstalled extesions

Tags: visual-studio-2010

During visual studio startup I get lots of annoying dialogs about extensions package loading errors.
All the extensions that fail to load are those I uninstalled.

I checked all the places mentioned in this article ([Bootstrapping of VS packages and VSIX extensions in VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/07/bootstrapping-of-vs-packages-and-vsix-extensions-in-vs2010.aspx)) and none of the extensions I get error for is there.

Is there somewhere else I can check?

I would "just" like to see where visual studio finds these references and kindly delete them all :)

[image: Visual studio error - package did not load correctly]

---

I found this folder in the windows registry:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3990449039-760197492-1239349315-1121\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Packages
```

It contains all the reference to extensions visual studio tries to load (mostly pointing to `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3990449039-760197492-1239349315-1121\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\InstalledProducts` subfolders).

I just renamed the folder of the extensions I did remove and I do not see load errors anymore.

I'm sure this could cause some side effects so is anyone aware of a better way to avoid visual studio trying to load uninstalled extensions?

Comment: So you read the message and looked in ActivityLog.xml?  What was unclear about it?

Comment: If the extensions are NOT installed, why does it keep trying to load them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Visual Studio HTM Editor Package did not load correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933913/the-visual-studio-htm-editor-package-did-not-load-correctly)

Comment: This solution worked for me on VS2012. I encountered this error after uninstalling StyleCop via appwiz.cpl (add/remove programs). Also, to simplify the navigation in the registry, it's a little more convenient to target HEKY_CURRENT_USER so that you don't have to include the SID of the user in the registry path.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608676/109941) is the correct answer:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. **Backup**, and then delete Visual Studio's `AppData` folder. For example:

   - ***Visual Studio 2010:***
     `%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0`
   - ***Visual Studio 2012:***
     `%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
   - ***Visual Studio 2013:***
     `%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`
3. Restart Visual Studio and enjoy.

Comment: this did not work for me for VS 2013 RC, Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @e10: I haven't tested VS 2013 RC, but I have every reason to believe that the fix would be the same, and that you should simply target a different folder.

Comment: I had this issue with VS2013, it didn't work, and the 12.0 folder has been deleted without success.

Comment: fixed it for me in 2013 - 1 error message was still showing up but I reinstalled the package and its now running without any issues.

Comment: just a side note, on Windows 7 and up `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is the same as `%APPDATA%\..\Local` and 4 characters shorter :)

Comment: This worked for me in VS2013 after deleting both the APPDATA folder in both the Roaming and Local folders

Comment: Had this problem after experiencing multiple failures trying to install VS 2010 SP1. I eventually had to find the log file (Look in %temp% for a file matching HFI*.tmp.html) and manually run the last set of .msp files mentioned there. And then delete that %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 folder

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this after upgrading SmartBear AQTime where I removed IDE integration (which doesn't work well anyway, may as well run standalone). VS2010 complained no startup about packages which didn't load correctly.

I actually deleted the contents of

AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions

and this fixed things entirely.

Comment: This could be helpful to other users but it would really be better as a comment on the accepted answer (you can add comments once you earn more rep).

Answer (score 0):

I encount this problem after removing devexpress from my computer,and I cleaned the registries yesterday，then I delete the devenv.CTM file in 
%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033 file and restart my VS, it works!