# C# form1 "There is no editor available for..."

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I try to open form1 in visual studio, I get an error saying `There is no editor available for [path directory] Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed`.

I did a complete uninstall of visual studio and installed it again and I still get the same error. When I go to the debug folder of my program it still runs... I just can't edit it.

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['There is no editor available' error in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932182/there-is-no-editor-available-error-in-vs-2010)

Comment: This is an environmental problem, you ought to greatly worry about the state of your machine's registry.  Right-click the item, Open With, select CSharp Editor and click the Set as Default button.  But with the expectation that this won't work either because your machine is kaput.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263701/how-does-visual-studio-choose-which-editor-to-use-for-a-file